# Mechanism for returning unreceived websockets

Tags: django, websocket, redis, daphne

*In my project, we are facing a problem that we cannot solve.*

**The technological context:**
Our application runs under Django and has Websockets. This stand in a Kube environment.
The http part with its API is managed by Django and DRF in Gunicorn pods.
The websockets and the asgi layer of the app are managed by Daphne in Daphne pods.
We use Channel for Django to support WS.
We use its ChannelRedis layer to share data in real time between the various server instances, allowing them to access the same websocket information.

**The functional context:**
We have users interacting with the application then the front hit the back via the API.
This then triggers a workflow which will, as it progresses, notify the front via WS messages.
All users'fronts receive these changes and are then updated.
Well, this is the classic principle of WS in fact.

**Our problem:**
It happens that some users no longer receive any WS messages (network problem, Daphne, Redis service interruption problem or other).
So these users no longer have the right values on their front..
After, the WS connection is reestablished, the next ws messages will be sent again.
Unfortunately, messages sent during the blackout period will never have been received.

**The question:**
How to retrieve WS messages sent during a disconnection period and resend them.

**What I was able to quickly imagine:**
Have an A list of messages to send.
We put the WS messages in it.
We pop this list A by sending the WS one by one.
Once sent, the message is put in a second B list.
When the front receives the WS it sends to the back a WS ACK notification with the uuid of the message to tell it "ok I received the message"
The back looks in list B for the message with this uuid and pops it.
Thus all messages that have been in this list for more than x seconds are messages that have not been received by the front and must be resent again.
We decided to put it in a Redis list for its responsiveness, but the problem is that it is stored in RAM, so if the Redis pod crashes: we lose the messages.
But what else should you store them in? In DB seems very heavy to me.

**Constraints:**
A constraint that I was able to see is that messages not received and then sent back risk arriving AFTER future messages. Which would give an inconsistency in the data on the front side.
At the front therefore check if the message is older than the last message.

I haven't seen much reading about this on the internet.
Are there any good practices in this type of situation?